# Reducing variable usage while checking a group of controls

Tags: c#, winforms, variables

I only want a warning to go up if none of the check boxes inside a group box are checked. This is what I'm using right now:

```
foreach(CheckBox i in groupBox_productType.Controls) {
    if(i.Checked){
        isChecked = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!isChecked) { /* warning goes here */ }
```

Without creating a one-time use variable (`isChecked`), is there a way of doing what I want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
if(!group_Box.productType.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Any( c => c.Checked ) )
{
...
}
```

This will also short circuit on the first "true" value, the same as your break.

Edit: Included cast to type of Checkbox per comment.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
if (!groupBox_productType.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Any(checkBox => checkBox.Checked))
{
  //Warning goes here.
}
```

Any will break soon as it find a match to any of the Controls in the group by of the type CheckBox that are checked.

Comment: Wouldn't that show the warning if there are any checked boxes, I thought he wanted it to show when there are none?